# The best pythonic way to include attributes in Q lookup using dictionary with the condition "OR"

Tags: python, django, lookup

When I include attributes in Qlookup using dictionary, they are used with the condition "AND". How best to set the condition "OR"?

```
from django.db.models import Q

query={'manufacturer':'1','release_date':'2019'}
lookups = Q(**query)
print(lookups) # (AND: ('manufacturer', '1'),('release_date', '2019'))
```

I would like to see something like " (OR: ('manufacturer', '1'),('release_date', '2019')) "

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

We can make a function here that will generate such `Q`:

```
from django.db.models import Q
from functools import reduce
from operator import or_

def q_or(**kwargs):
    if kwargs:
        return reduce(or_, map(Q, kwargs.items()))
    return Q(pk__in=())
```

The `Q(pk__in=())` is something we here construct that is always `False`. It is returned if there is no item at all in the `**kwargs`.

We can then use this with:

```
lookups = q_or(**{'manufacturer':'1','release_date':'2019'})
```

or more elegantly:

```
lookups = q_or(manufacturer='1', release_date='2019')
```

This will give us:

```
>>> q_or(manufacturer='1', release_date='2019')
<Q: (OR: ('manufacturer', '1'), ('release_date', '2019'))>
```

Comment: I did not know `Q` can take a 2-tuple in place of a keyword argument. Updated my answer to adopt your simpler mapping method. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can set `lookups` to the first query constraint in the dict items, and use the `|=` operator in a loop to keep aggregating the `Q` object `lookups` with constraints specified by the rest of the dict items:

```
lookups, *rest = map(Q, query.items())
for constraint in rest:
    lookups |= constraint
```

With your sample input, `print(lookups)` will output:

```
<Q: (OR: ('manufacturer', '1'), ('release_date', '2019'))>
```